# Auto Delete MongoDB documents after 30d

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, mongodb, express

I building a calendar app with React & Express.js & Mongo DB
the calendar has month view displays weekly events, and i want to delete these events automaticlly after 30 days

my schema.ts:

```html
import { Calendar } from "../types";

const calendarSchema = new mongoose.Schema<Calendar>(
  {
    startDate: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    endDate: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    rRule: {
      type: String,
    },
    title: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    notes: {
      type: String,
      // required: true,
    },
    type: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    expireAt: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

calendarSchema.index({ expireAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 70 });

export default mongoose.model<Calendar>("Calendar", calendarSchema);
```

and i am creating a "expireAt" field in my front-end like:

```html
const payload = await createAppointment({
      ...appointment,
      expireAt: new Date().getTime() + 80,
    });
```

now this deletes documents in 40 - 50 seconds, my question is how can i make it 30 or 31 days ?
thanks in advance .

Answer (score 2):

Change `expireAt` to `Date` instead of `number`

And when creating an index assign 0 to `expireAfterSeconds`

```
calendarSchema.index({ expireAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 });
```

Now you can define the exact date of when each Calendar will expire, from yearly or down back to seconds

For more info, check MongoDB's [documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)

Comment: thanks sir, it worked after i deleted the previeus index, i had createdAt index, it deleted it, it works now, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you set expiry to be after 70 seconds:

```
calendarSchema.index({ expireAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 70 });
```

Instead of 70 in the `expireAfterSeconds` just push the value you want, for example for 7 days:

```
60 * 60 * 24 * 7 = 604800
```